# How can I create the following table?

Tags: multicolumn, multirow

How can I create the following table?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should be able to create this table by looking around on this site for similar peojects. You can also try Google. There are different approaches for typesetting such tables. It would be best if you could come up with a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you tried so far and where exactly you got stuck. This site is not exactly a manual for everything, so you should probably first familiarize yourself with how to typeset tables in general.

Comment: Start with a tabular with 9 columns and use `\multicolumn{3}{c}{Part 3}` and similar for `Part 4` and also for the foot.

Comment: Should the "Part 1" and "Part 2" column groups have the same widths as the "Part 3" and "Part 4" column groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: After taking into account the comments from @Mico, I realised that there is no need to use the `multirow` package and any commands associated with it. The following code still produces the desired output:

```
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[]
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|ccc|ccc|c|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Part 1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Part 2} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Part   3}                                                                               & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Part   4}                                                                               & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Sum}   \\ \hline
                       &           & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Q1}                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Q2}                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Q3}   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Q1}                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Q2}                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Q3}   &        \\ \cline{3-8}
            &                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &          & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &         &                            \\
            &                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  &                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  &                           &                            \\
            &                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  &                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  &                           &                            \\
            &                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  &                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  &                           &                            \\
            &                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  &                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  &                           &                            \\
            &                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  &                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  &                           &                            \\
            &                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  &                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  &                           &                            \\
            &                             & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  &                           & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                  &                           &                            \\ \cline{3-8}
            &                             & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{5pts}              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{5pts}              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{5pts} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{5pts}              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{5pts}              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{5pts} &                            \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{30pts}  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{20pts}  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{15pts}                                                                                  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{15pts}                                                                                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{80pts} \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Below is the output as it is appearing in the sketch diagram posted by @DSPinfinity:
[image]

Comment: Package`multirow` not `multicol`. BTW: You wouldn't need so many `\multicolumn{1}{c|}`, if you'd add the `|` to the column specification of the `tabular`.

Comment: What's the purpose of `\multirow{10}{*}{}` and `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{8}{*}{}}`?

Comment: The purpose of `\multirow{10}{*}{}` and `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{8}{*}{}}` is of increasing the white space e.g the white space between the labelling Part 1 and 30 pts is 10 rows while the whitespace between the labelling Q1 and 5pts is 8 rows in length.

Comment: Hint: Remove all `\multirow` directives and check if the output is different.

Comment: Thanks @Mico. I greatly appreciate your comment.

Comment: +1 for extra effort :-)

Answer (score 3):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\color{red}
\begin{NiceTabular}{*9{c}}[hvlines]
  Part 1 & Part 2  & \Block{1-3}{Part 3} &&& \Block{1-3}{Part 4} &&& Sum  \\
  \Block{3-1}{} & \Block{3-1}{} & 01 & 02 & 03 & 01 & 02 & 03 & \Block{3-1}{} \\
                                                                          \\[3cm]
         & & 5\,pts & 5\,pts & 5\,pts & 5\,pts & 5\,pts & 5\,pts \\
  30\,pts & 20\,pts & \Block{1-3}{15\,pts}&&& \Block{1-3}{15\,pts} &&& 80\,pts \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 2):

Here an example with the `tabular` features of the LaTeX kernel only:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\color{red}
\begin{tabular}{|*9{c|}}
  \hline
  Part 1 & Part 2  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Part 3} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Part 4} & Sum \\
  \hline
         & & 01 & 02 & 03 & 01 & 02 & 03 & \\
  \cline{3-8}
         & & & & & & & & \\
         & & & & & & & & \\
         & & & & & & & & \\
         & & & & & & & & \\
         & & & & & & & & \\
         & & & & & & & & \\
  \cline{3-8}
         & & 5\,pts & 5\,pts & 5\,pts & 5\,pts & 5\,pts & 5\,pts & \\
  \hline
  30\,pts & 20\,pts & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{15\,pts}& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{15\,pts} & 80\,pts \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But as an alternative, you could use, e.g., package `tabularx`, `tabularray`, `hhline` and a lot of other packages. You could even make if more fancy using packages like `xcolor` and `colortbl` or TikZ or …

Answer (score 2):

The OP didn't state this explicitly, but I will assume that they want the five header cells -- "Part 1" thru "Sum" -- to have equal widths. To achieve this objective, I suggest (a) setting up a 5*3=15-column `tabularx` environment, (b) setting the table's target width to `\textwidth`, and (c) using `\multicolumn{3}` directives to typeset the contents of the combined cells in the first and last row.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{tabularx}   % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' column type
\usepackage{ragged2e}   % for '\Centering' macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X} % centered version of 'X' column type

\begin{document}
\noindent
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}% default: 6pt
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}% % optional, for a more open "look"
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| *{3}{C} | *{3}{C} | *{6}{C|} *{3}{C} |}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Part 1} &
\multicolumn{3}{ c|}{Part 2} &
\multicolumn{3}{ c|}{Part 3} &
\multicolumn{3}{ c|}{Part 4} &
\multicolumn{3}{ c|}{Sum} \\
\hline
& & & & & & 01 & 02 & 03 & 01 & 02 & 03 & & & \\
\cline{7-12}
& & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\ % fill in the blanks...
& & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
& & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
& & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
& & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
& & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\cline{7-12}
& & & & & & 5\,pts & 5\,pts & 5\,pts & 5\,pts & 5\,pts & 5\,pts & & & \\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{30\,pts} &
\multicolumn{3}{ c|}{20\,pts} &
\multicolumn{3}{ c|}{15\,pts} &
\multicolumn{3}{ c|}{15\,pts} &
\multicolumn{3}{ c|}{80\,pts} \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```